# Generate and publish PointCloud2 in ros2?

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp, ros-crystal, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's the most convenient way to generate a bunch of points in a loop, assign xyz (and possibly rgb), and then publish as a PointCloud2?  I'm interested in a full C++ code example mainly but python would be useful to have here also.

With and without pcl would be useful too.  pcl_ros isn't available in crystal but there is pcl_conversions `ros-crystal-pcl-conversions`.  I encountered some [oddities with linking to PCL in colcon/ament](https://github.com/ros2/pcl_conversions/issues/3) last time I tried, maybe that is better addressed in a separate question but CMakeLists.txt excerpts are additionally helpful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312587/generate-and-publish-pointcloud2-in-ros2?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2019-01-12

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2019-01-12**:
Cross referencing https://github.com/lucasw/imgui_ros/issues/57

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### c++ with pcl_conversions

https://github.com/lucasw/imgui_ros/blob/crystal/imgui_ros/src/test/generate_pointcloud2.cpp

```
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/msg/point_cloud2.hpp>
#include <tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h>
...
pub_ = create_publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>("point_cloud");
...
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> cloud_;
// TODO(lucasw) generate a cube or sphere instead, more interesting than 2d
for (int i = 0; i < num_points_; ++i) {
  const float fr = static_cast<float>(i) / static_cast<float>(num_points_);
  pcl::PointXYZRGB pt;
  pt = pcl::PointXYZRGB(fr * 255, 255 - fr * 255, 18 + fr * 20);
  pt.x = cos(fr * M_PI * 2.0) * 1.0;
  pt.y = sin(fr * M_PI * 2.0) * 1.0;
  pt.z = 0.0;
  cloud_.points.push_back(pt);
}

pc2_msg_ = std::make_shared<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>();
pcl::toROSMsg(cloud_, *pc2_msg_);
pc2_msg_->header.frame_id = "map";
...

pc2_msg_->header.stamp = now();
pub_->publish(pc2_msg_);
```

And in cmake:

```
add_executable(generate_pointcloud2 src/test/generate_pointcloud2.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(generate_pointcloud2
  "geometry_msgs"  # maybe don't need this
  "pcl_conversions"
  "rcl_interfaces"
  "rclcpp"
  "rcutils"
  "sensor_msgs"
  "std_msgs"
  "tf2_geometry_msgs"
)
target_link_libraries(generate_pointcloud2
  ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}  # pcl_conversions requires this
)
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2019-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-09-29**:
Shouldn't dereferencing be required? `pub_->publish(*pc2_msg_);`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to complement... I also had to add into the CmakeList the following command:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
```

---

Originally posted by [mirella melo](https://answers.ros.org/users/55539/mirella-melo/) with karma: 194 on 2020-07-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1